# Effective vba range

Tags: vba, range

Below is what is running,but I only want this effective on, for example B10 to H13 on sheet one. Is there a simple way to choose the range of the vba?
Usually Excel offers a range button, but not in this case I belive.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
       Cancel = True
    Worksheet_SelectionChange Target

End Sub
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  'If the target cell is clear
     If Target.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone Then

        'Then change the background to the specified color
        Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 4

        'But if the target cell is already the specified color
        ElseIf Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 4 Then

        'Then change the background to the specified color
        Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 3

        'But if the target cell is already the specified color
        ElseIf Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then

        'Then clear the background color
        Target.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I find it helpful to record a macro while manually doing what I want to do in code. Then look at the macro code to see how things can be done.

Comment: try googling "only run macro for specific range" and see if that gets you going in the right direction...

Comment: I don't know if I misunderstood something. If you want to run your code on the Range B10:H13 instead of the active selection, replace `Target` by `Range("B10:H13")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited...not sure if that's what you're after exactly, but it should give you a good start.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
       Cancel = True
    Worksheet_SelectionChange Target

End Sub
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    'If the target cell is within the range
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("B10:H13")) Is Nothing Then

        'If the target cell is clear
         If Target.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone Then

            'Then change the background to the specified color
            Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 4

            'But if the target cell is already the specified color
            ElseIf Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 4 Then

            'Then change the background to the specified color
            Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 3

            'But if the target cell is already the specified color
            ElseIf Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then

            'Then clear the background color
            Target.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone

        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Im not exactly sure where to insert it...Im not used to working with vba's.

Comment: Brilliant! This is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is what you want, but you can exit the sub with the following code if the target is not inside the B10:H13 range:

```
    If Intersect(Target, Range("B10:H13")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
```

Comment: In addition, is it possible to add more cells within the same line. If I would like to have B10:H13 and G13:V14 and so on?

Comment: You can use something like `Range("B10:H13,G13:V14")` . You can also extend the range using Union()

Comment: Absolutely Brilliant!